# How to add custom controls in the app bar in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I want to add custom controls, like a slider bar or a button in the secondary section of the app bar in windows phone 8.1, like the one in the app bar of camera app.
[image]

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: You might want to change ControlTemplate of these buttons, you can surely insert slider there

Comment: @quirell can you plz tell how to do that?

Comment: Ok I'll show you when l'm at the computer, it will be in a few hours, but just open your page in blend put normal button on design pane, edit style, add slider there and apply this style to appbarbutton, should work

Comment: @ac-lab First of all the camera app actually do not have an AppBar. The control that's opening by pressing three dots at bottom, is a Custom Control made by developer of that Camera App. check that control's opening and closing animation and try to relate it with actual AppBar control's animation. 

You'll find that developers of that app, used a customized uesr control same as Bottom AppBar and used it in the App.

Answer (score 2):

So, it appears, that my solution works only in designer, tried another, but which also only worked in designer. So I would conclude that it is impossible to put in commandbar anything other than default buttons, my attempts were as following:

I tried to apply this style to AppbarButoon, button changed to slider in designer, but on the phone it style has been overriden

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneButtonFontWeight}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="9.5,0"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneButtonMinHeight}"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneButtonMinWidth}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="Transparent">
                            <Slider ValueChanged="RangeBase_OnValueChanged"  Width="100" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Second approach was to derive from slider and implement ICommandBarElement, it seemed to be working untill I run it under emulator, Slider didn't even showed up.

```
 public sealed class CommandBarSlider : Slider, ICommandBarElement
    {
        public CommandBarSlider()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Slider);
        }

        public bool IsCompact { get; set; }
    }
```

The obvious conclusion to be drawn from these codes is that what you're trying to do is either impossible, or I've overlooked something.

(Probably I've overlooked something )

Comment: I have been stuck on this problem for a while too. I'm just puzzled to how the MS IE team managed to add a textbox control to the appbar in internet explorer for WP8 - unless they recreated the entire thing from the ground up?